# What is the dimension of the projection of a set of points onto a plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$?

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, projective-geometry, plane-geometry

I know that $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ is a plane a 2 dimensional subset of a 3D space, as it has 2 degrees of freedom (choosing the value of 2 variables determines the value of the third).

Now given the projection of a set of points onto this plane, can it have dimension 3?

Comment: Please, clearly state your question and gives us some context, we can make pretty reasonable assumptions, but often not entirely accurate.

Comment: @Jiaze if draw on the plane  Ax+By+Cz+D=0 gives image 2D or3D?

Comment: @Jiaze but if we kept projection plane at any $z_{vp}$, then how $z=0$?

Comment: What are you referring to when you mention $z_{vp}$? Your question is not clear at all, you are talking about the projection plane, but you are not stating which is the projection plane, nor what do you mean by "drawing" nor what are you even trying to project nor even what is the "image" you are talking about. When talking about mathematics, you have to be precise about what you are asking about.

Comment: @jiaze I am saying if I placed projection plane at any z value on z-axis, then projection of {(x,y,z)∈R3} , how z=0 in projection plane?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131624/discussion-between-jiaze-zhang-and-sood).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is at most 2D.

When you have a point $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$, and you project it to a point $(a',b',c')\in\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:Ax+By+Cz+D=0\}$, this point still has at most degree of freedom 2, because it still satisfies the equation of the plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$: setting 2 values of this equation automatically determines the value of the third one.

Comment: Could you please answer this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4311171/how-2d-image-could-be-seen-after-using-z-value